# How do you match more than one node using Freemarker?

Tags: xml, freemarker

My FreeMarker FTL code is the following:

```
<a class="launch" href="${item.target-url}">View Now</a>
```

I am pulling a snippet from the following XML:

```
<item>
 <target-url>www.test.com/jimmy</target-url>    
</item>
<item>
 <target-url></target-url>  
</item>
<item>
 <target-url></target-url>  
</item>
```

I figure that this should work.

But when I view my html page I get the following error:

Exception when trying to transform with the FTL template! freemarker.core.NonNumericalException: For "-" left-hand operand: Expected a number, but this evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel): ==> item.target [in template "marketing/widgets/freemarker/newblogpost-update.ftl" at line 31, column 105] ---- Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches. ---- ---- FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related): - Failed at: ${item.target - url?size != 0} [in template "marketing/widgets/freemarker/newblogpost-update.ftl" at line 31, column 103] ----

I figure that I am getting this error because my XML contains multiple nodes () that don't contain data. Some of my nodes may contain data but not all of them. Is there a way that I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because you have `-` sign in XML tag and FreeMarker treats it like a minus sign: `${item.target - key}`

So you have to use that construction:

```
${item["target-url"]}
```

[FAQ](http://freemarker.org/docs/app_faq.html#faq_strange_variable_name)

Comment: works great! I was thinking the name had something to do with it

Comment: You can also write that like this: `${item.target\-url}`.

Comment: Good to know as well. I asked the admin to refrain from using - when naming XML elements. I think that should work well